# The argument in golang RPC call

Tags: go, rpc

In the RPC handler function, I omit the first argument like:

```
func (self Handler) GetName(int, reply *StructObj) {
}
```

and in the calling side

```
var reply StructObj
client.Call("Handler.GetName", 0, &reply)
```

Because I do not need the first argument in the GetName Method, I omit its name,
HOWEVER, I got:

```
gob: type mismatch in decoder: want struct type
```

I changed the GetName method to GetName(id int, reply *StructObj) and it works.
I want to know why this happened?

Comment: You can use underscore to signify that you don't want the variable. `GetName(_ int, reply *StructObj)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hit a tricky aspect of function definition syntax in Go. You can't have an unnamed argument, and you *can* name an argument `int`, and `func f(x, y, z Type)` is a shortcut to declare all three variables to be of type `Type`. For example, `func f(int, x string)` counterintuitively declares an `f` that accepts *two strings*, one of which happens to be named `int`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f(int, x string) {
    fmt.Println("int is:", int)
    fmt.Println("x is:", x)
}

func main() {
    f("foo", "bar")
}
```

[When you run it](http://play.golang.org/p/WazrwrxNs8), the output is

```
int is: foo
x is: bar
```

Yes, that's a little mind-bending. I've never heard the specific thinking explained, but maybe they kept builtin type names un-reserved so they could later introduce new builtin types without breaking code that's already out there.

Anyway, it means your first function definition doesn't actually accept an int and a `*StructObj` but *a `*StructObj` named `int`* and another named `reply`. So the error message from `net/rpc` actually means that the client passed a 0 when it expected a `*StructObj`. Pretty fun.

Comment: Wow!!I never know the go will respect 'int' as a name of variable !! Thank you !!

Comment: It also matches the behavior of the binding of structs with "embedded" anonymous fields.  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types